# What does 'go the way of the blue suede shoe' mean?

Tags: meaning

In REVIVAL written by Stephen King, its main character adored an old horse, and he said most of his teeth had 'gone the way of the blue suede shoe' years ago. Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: Blue suede shoes are no longer in style. They're gone, just like the main character's teeth. In other words, he's almost toothless.

Comment: In your [other question](/q/353521) you stated that the main character worked at a recording studio: the answer to that question was a popular song. What has your research turned up for this question? For example, sixty years ago these shoes were the [height of fashion](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=1141), wonderful things, if not easy to clean. But now...

Comment: @deadrat - Probably because someone stepped on them.

Comment: @deadrat I've got some blue suede shoes I bought about 5 years ago, but they aren't bright blue and they don't have thick crepe soles!

Answer (score 1):

> Blue suede shoes are no longer in style. They're gone, just like the main character's teeth. In other words, he's almost toothless. – **deadrat**